# Trying to make a SSH Tunel

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, tunneling

I configurated a bastion server on AWS on my public subnet. 
I can make direct ssh to the ec2 instance inside the private subnet, using the bastion host.

I can connect to the bastion host and check if the 7474 port on the private ec2 istance is opened.

```
nc -v -z -w 5 10.0.3.102 7474; echo $?
Connection to 10.0.3.102 7474 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
0
```

I want to ssh tunnel from a localhost (my home machine) to a ec2 instance on private network.

```
ssh -v -C -N -L 9000:PRIVATE_MDM:7474 BASTION
```

But i getting:

> open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

```
Authenticated to 52.32.240.40 ([52.32.240.40]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:9000 forwarded to remote address PRIVATE_MDM:7474
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 9000.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 9000.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Connection to port 9000 forwarding to PRIVATE_MDM port 7474 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 9000 forwarding to PRIVATE_MDM port 7474 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9000 for PRIVATE_MDM port 7474, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 42685 to 127.0.0.1 port 9000, nchannels 4
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9000 for PRIVATE_MDM port 7474, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 42686 to 127.0.0.1 port 9000, nchannels 3
debug1: Connection to port 9000 forwarding to PRIVATE_MDM port 7474 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9000 for PRIVATE_MDM port 7474, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 42687 to 127.0.0.1 port 9000, nchannels 3
```

Comment: If it does not help, try to search for the reasons in the server log or try to run server in debug mode. It should tell you more precise reasons.

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BASTION` machine has forbidden to create port forwarding by option `AllowTcpForwarding`. If you want to have port-forwarding working, you need to allow this option on this machine.

**EDIT:**  Now I see the flaw there. Can you add description what are you trying to achieve? Forwarding your non-used local port to non-used remote port does not make sense. You either forward existing service on remote side to your local port (then use `-L` -- local port forwarding) or the other way round, your local service to remote port (then you use `-R` -- remote port forwarding). Without this, you can't proceed further.

**SOLUTION:** Difference between `nc` and `ssh` command in examples is in usage of direct IP address and `hostname`. The `BASTION` was not able to resolve `PRIVATE_MDM` which caused the problem.

Comment: I already set: (on file etc/ssh/sshd_config)
PermitTunnel yes
AllowTCPForwarding yes

Comment: Did you restart your `sshd` after that? `PermitTunel` is unrelated.

Comment: Yep. service ssh restart

Comment: I am trying to connect to a service on port 7474 on a ec2 instance inside a private subnet. So I create a bastion server. I want to connect to the bastion server and redirect the traffic to the 7474 on the private server.

Comment: yes. My service is running on 7474 port on PRIVATE_MDM. I can connect to the bastion and then connect to the PRIVATE_MDM (nc -v -z -w 5 10.0.3.102 7474; echo $?). I can make an ssh from my client machine direct to the PRIVATE_MDM.

Comment: Yes, i can! It is a web app running on 7474 port. I just make this command nc -v -z -w 5 10.0.3.102 7474; echo $? from the bastion server, and get 'Connection to 10.0.3.102 7474 port [tcp/*] succeeded!'

Comment: I found the problem! The bastion server could not resolve PRIVATE_MDM!
Thanks mann!!!

Comment: Yes. That was the only difference between the `nc` and `ssh` command.

Comment: Update the question with my response. I will accept your answer

Comment: Updated according to problem. Glad to help.